# Node: fill config array from API

Tags: node.js, scope, callback, config

I need to fill my config object

```
var config = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: /* make an api request here */,
};
```

with a value of a API-request (http). The API returns a Json string like:

```
{ configValue: 3 }
```

How to write a function which fills in the `configValue` from the API request?

I tried that:

```
const request = require('request');
var config = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: function() {
        request.get('http://api-url',(err, res, body) => {
             return JSON.parse(res.body).configValue;
        };
    }(),
};
console.log(config);
```

but the result is `undefined`:

```
{ one: 1, two: 2, three: undefined }
```

Comment: You are missing basic knowledge of JavaScript asynchronous work. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321

Comment: I'm new to Node, indeed. But this is no browser environment (no Ajax here) but a Node backend server running. How would a Node-like solution look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the request to finish before you start your code.

Try this for example:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

const getConfig = async () => {

    const fromUrl = await request.get('http://api-url');

    return {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        three: fromUrl
    }

};

getConfig().then(config => {
    // Do here whatever you need based on your config
});
```

Comment: Thanks, good hint. But the config-array must be as stated in my question (top-level).  I am maintaining an existing software and I cannot change the config-array. So how would a solution look like inside the config array?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any array in your code. If you can't change the code you are maintaining I guess you can't maintain it...

Comment: Sorry, I mean the config object.

Comment: You can put the async code wherever you want, but the code that depends on it must wait for the request to complete before it get executed... You can do it by `callbacks`, `promises`, ar `aync/await`, your choice.